# Subtracting a cell value with all other cells and finding largest value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: CELL VALUE]

I have the above list of values. I want to first subtract first value with all other values. After that subtracting second value with all others and so on. Final result should be largest subtraction value and two cells which generated the largest subtraction value.

Comment: Picture is not relevant. It's just for illustrative purpose.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a VBA solution, try the next code, please. Basically it adapts the formula suggestions made above by @Tom Sharpe:

```
Sub testLargestSubtraction()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, rng As Range, maxSubstrVal As Double
 Dim maxCellAddress As String, minCellAddress As String, rngMaxS As Range
 
  Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  Set rng = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
  maxSubstrVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(rng) - WorksheetFunction.Min(rng)
  maxCellAddress = "A" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0) + rng.cells(1).row - 1
  minCellAddress = "A" & WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Min(rng), rng, 0) + rng.cells(1).row - 1
  Debug.Print maxSubstrVal, maxCellAddress, minCellAddress
  Set rngMaxS = Union(sh.Range(maxCellAddress), sh.Range(minCellAddress))
  rngMaxS.Select
End Sub
```

It returns (in Immediate Window) what you asked for and also selects the two cells which produces the largest subtraction result, independent of the range sorting.

Answer (score 2):

If understand your question as wanting to find the largest difference between any of your numbers, the answer is simply

```
Max(numbers)-Min(numbers)
```

Making the simplest assumption, that there are six numbers and they are sorted into descending order, the answers are:

```
457.05-112.3 => 344.75 , maximum at A1, minimum at A6.
```

by inspection.

More generally, if you have a variable number of numbers, not sorted, the largest difference is:

```
=MAX(A:A)-MIN(A:A)
```

The largest value is at:

```
=MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0)
```

And the smallest value at:

```
=MATCH(MIN(A:A),A:A,0)
```

You *can* create a matrix to compare all the possible pairs of numbers, but the answer will be the same. This would be only be necessary if you wanted to find the second largest, third largest difference etc.